# Why should two java files that differ only in comments produce different class files?

Tags: java, class, comments

I have a file called **One.java** that has only one commented line. I compiled it to produce the class file **One.class** and Renamed it as **old.class**. Then, I opened **One.java**, introduced five more commented lines and compiled it again to produce **One.class**. Both the class files had the **same size**, but when I ran diff on them like:
`diff One.class old.class`
I got the output:

```
Binary files One.class and old.class differ
```

This is my **One.java** file:

```
// One.java
class One
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello Java world");
    }
}
```

and this is my revised **One.java** (with additional lines of comment):

```
// One.java
// One.java
// One.java
// One.java
// One.java
// One.java
class One
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello Java world");
    }
}
```

I am using Java SE 10 on an iMac running High Sierra.

Comment: Would you like to show us the class files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debugging symbols; basically the code includes line numbers and other metadata for debugging. You can examine it yourself with `javap -v One.class` and `javap -v old.class`

Comment: Most prominently, the line numbers differ.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Actually, that's probably all that differs (here anyway).